# Python convert list of nested tuples to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of nested tuples as

```
[(('p1', 'p2'), ('m1',)), (('p2', 'p1'), ('m1',))]
```

How can i convert it into list of tuples as

```
[('p1', 'p2', 'm1'), ('p2', 'p1', 'm1')]
```

without using for loop

Comment: Are the tuples nested arbitrary deep? Or only two levels?

Comment: Fixed, only two levels

Comment: Are `for`s in a list comprehension allowed? That is just a different kind of `for` loop, really.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `for`? Is this an homework? What have you done so far? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain),

```
In [91]: from itertools import chain
In [92]: [tuple(chain(*item)) for item in a]
Out[92]: [('p1', 'p2', 'm1'), ('p2', 'p1', 'm1')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use *list comprehension* with a *generator* as element in the `tuple(..)` constructor:

```
[tuple(x for elem in row for x in elem) for row in data]
```

The code fragment in **boldface** is a *generator*: for every `row` (i.e. `(('p1', 'p2'), ('m1',))`) it yield the elements that are two levels deep so: `p1`, `p2` and `m1`. These are converted into a `tuple`.

Or you can use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain

[tuple(chain(*row)) for row in data]
```

This generates:

```
>>> data = [(('p1', 'p2'), ('m1',)), (('p2', 'p1'), ('m1',))]
>>> [tuple(x for elem in row for x in elem) for row in data]
[('p1', 'p2', 'm1'), ('p2', 'p1', 'm1')]
>>> [tuple(chain(*row)) for row in data]
[('p1', 'p2', 'm1'), ('p2', 'p1', 'm1')]
```

You can also use `itertools.starmap(..)` and `list(..)` to remove the list comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain, starmap

list(map(tuple,starmap(chain,data)))
```

Which gives:

```
>>> list(map(tuple,starmap(chain,data)))
[('p1', 'p2', 'm1'), ('p2', 'p1', 'm1')]
```

Note that although you do not *write* a `for` loop yourself, of course there is still a loop mechanism in place at the list comprehension or `map(..)` and `starmap(..)` functions.

Comment: Can i do it using something from itertools like chain(*) something like that. Not sure. Don't want to use "for"

Comment: @Nitin: yes. That's an alternative way to do it. As is demonstrated.