# Flatten Nested Tuples in a List of a List of Nested Tuples More Pythonically

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

So, I've generated a list of lists of nested tuples (vectors for a chess move authenticator).

```
old_v = [[((4, 1, 'P', 'e2'), 1), ((4, 2, '1', 'e3'), 0), ((4, 3, '1', 'e4'), 0), ((4, 4, '1', 'e5'), 0), ((4, 5, '1', 'e6'), 0), ((4, 6, 'q', 'e7'), -1)]]
```

After reading documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643557/flattening-a-list-of-tuples) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43425730/python-convert-list-of-nested-tuples-to-list-of-tuples), I still wasn't able to figure out how to collapse just the tuples from inside each sub-list without rewriting the whole tuple, like this:

```
new_v = [[(a[b][0][0], a[b][0][1], a[b][0][2], a[b][0][3], a[b][1]) for b in range(0, len(a))] for a in old_v]

print(new_v)
```

I'd like to know if there's a more Pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Which output are you looking for? `a[0][1]` seems unusual, did you mean `a[b][1]`?

Comment: I did. I'll adjust it accordingly.

Comment: you can refer to the article [How to make a flat lists](stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists), @Shawn Chin's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[(a[b][0][0], a[b][0][1], a[b][0][2], a[b][0][3], a[b][1]) for b in range(0, len(a))]
```

All of the references to `b` are as `a[b]`, so you can loop over the elements directly instead of going through indexes:

```
[(b[0][0], b[0][1], b[0][2], b[0][3], b[1]) for b in a]
```

Tuple unpacking can make `b[0]` and `b[1]` more readable and meaningful if you have good names for them:

```
[(move[0], move[1], move[2], move[3], idk) for move, idk in a]
```

Finally, iterables can be expanded in tuple literals with a splat:

```
[(*move, idk) for move, idk in a]
# or [move + (idk,) for move, idk in a] if you prefer
```

Overall:

```
new_v = [[(*move, idk) for move, idk in a] for a in old_v]
```

Comment: TIL about splat. Appreciative!

Also, for those reading, "move" should read "position". These are vectors, listed as lists of quintuples, that show up when pieces are pinned or in check.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
l = [((4, 1, 'P', 'e2'), 1), ((4, 2, '1', 'e3'), 0), ((4, 3, '1', 'e4'), 0), ((4, 4, '1', 'e5'), 0), ((4, 5, '1', 'e6'), 0), ((4, 6, 'q', 'e7'), -1)]

def flatten(list_):
    return [(*tup, i) for (tup, i) in list_]

>>> flatten(l)
[(4, 1, 'P', 'e2', 1), (4, 2, '1', 'e3', 1), (4, 3, '1', 'e4', 1), (4, 4, '1', 'e5', 1), (4, 5, '1', 'e6', 1), (4, 6, 'q', 'e7', 1)]
```

Comment: For a simple list, this works. However, for a list of lists, it would take an extra `for` loop or list comprehension.